# Problems in installing Laravel Envoy with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-envoy

When i try to install laravel envoy and run this command:

composer global require "laravel/envoy=~1.0"

I received this answer in terminal:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy v1.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy 1.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy 1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/envoy 1.0.2
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/process v3.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/envoy ~1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/envoy[1.0.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.5, v1.0.11, v1.0.12, v1.0.13, v1.0.14, v1.0.15, v1.0.16, v1.0.17, v1.0.18, v1.0.19, v1.0.20, v1.0.21, v1.0.22, v1.0.23, v1.0.24, v1.0.25, v1.0.26, v1.0.27, v1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.0.4
    - laravel/envoy 1.0.0 requires symfony/process 2.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.0, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.1, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.10, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.2, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.3, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.4, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.5, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.6, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.7, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.8, v3.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.9, v3.0.4].
    - Installation request for symfony/process == 3.0.4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.0.4].
```

My composer.json file in ~/.composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^1.3"
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Can you post what global package you already have.  My guess is there is something already installed that has a different requirement that is causing you issues

Comment: You need my composer.json and composer.lock located in project root or in .composer ?

Comment: Just the composer.json... I suspect there is some conflict there.

Comment: please put it in the original question.  hit edit and paste your composer.json file from the system... not your project

Comment: not that composer.json file... the one located possibly at `~/.composer/composer.json`

Comment: I added two composer.json files in original question, see it.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution to this problem.

This problem exists because Laravel 5.2 need symfony/process 2.8.* | 3.0.* and Envoy need symfony/process 2.4.* and when you are using higher symfony/process version, It faces some trouble in order to realize the difference of versions.

**Solution:**

Open composer.json file in ~/.composer:

```
$ vi ~/.composer/composer.json
```

It should look like this:

```
{
        "require": {
            "laravel/installer": "^1.3"
        }
    }
```

Change it to:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/envoy": "~1.0",
        "laravel/installer": "^1.3"
       }
}
```

Now use:

```
$ composer global require "laravel/envoy=~1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to make your composer alias available from your $PATH

```
composer global require laravel/envoy
```

You may need to (if not already) add your global composer directory to your $PATH
Add this line into your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```